# Using OSMdroid in the emulator

Tags: android, osmdroid

Ive read for testing map activities in the emulator you can pass in gps coordinates.

Im using OSMdroid. When I start up the activity in the emulator the map doesnt even show up. Is there anything different I have to do using OSMdroid to get the map to show up in the emulator?

Comment: You must use osmdroid version 4.1 or later. Earlier versions now fail to download tiles owing to an invalid UserAgent.

Comment: im using 4.2. Sorry should of said that in the original post.

Comment: It's likely to download a very empty bit of sea by default as that is what is at 0,0.  Are you sure this is not what your looking at?  what do you see?

Comment: Its not water. Theres no blue  or anything. Its just a load of small white/grey squares.

Comment: That sounds like the default before you get tiles back.

Comment: Yeah it is but the tiles never come it just stays like that indefinitely. Is there something i have to do to get the map to download?